# Given an $*$-algebra, when I can construct a codimension 1 subalgbera?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, operator-algebras

For the case of finite type algebras, the question is answered easily by **Proposition 1.1.1** in the first Kadison-Ringrose book on operator algebras, and the answer is obviously yes. Let's stick with countably type algebras. Is there any chance to construct a subalgebra of codimension $1$? In other words, viewing the algebra as a vector space, this would mean that the notion of hyperplane is immediately extendible from finite dimensional algebras to infinite dimensional algebras and, furthermore such an hyperplane would inherit a *-algebra structure.
Can someone give me an example in the case of the countable type algebra $\cal K(H)$ of compact operators over an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$?
I there any chance to construct such objects in other infinite non-countable type algebras?

Answer (score 2):

The result you quote is a result about vector spaces, not about algebras.

For $*$-algebras, what you want fails even in finite-dimension. The easiest example is the fact that $M_2(\mathbb C)$, of dimension $4$, does not admit a $*$-subalgebra of dimension $3$. For a $3$-dimensional $*$-subalgebra of a C$*$-algebra is necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbb C^3$; in particular it has three pairwise orthogonal projections, which is impossible in $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Of course it's true that every $3$-dimensional $\ast$-*subalgebra* of $M_2(\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^3$ by Wedderburn's theorem. But now I'm curious: Do you have an argument why this is true for arbitrary $3$-dim. $\ast$-algebras?

Comment: No, of course not. Consider any $3$-dimensional vector space with selfadjoint basis and the zero product. But if the $*$-algebra lives inside a C$^*$-algebra then it is a C$^*$-algebra itself. And a finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra is necessarily a direct sum of full matrix algebras; in the particular case of dimension $3$ inside $M_2(\mathbb C)$, the only possibility is three $1$-dimensional blocks. No need for Wedderburn (and no need for the parent C$^*$-algebra to be a matrix algebra).

Comment: You're right with the counterexample. "And a finite-dimensional C∗-algebra is necessarily a direct sum of full matrix algebras" - it may be a bit pretentious, but that's what I call Wedderburn's theorem for finite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras.